# How to show keystrokes of dead keys in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unicode, dead-key

In Visual Studio I want to use a character which is composed of a dead key plus another key.

I type this :         `   +    e  ->  è

VS takes it as :       96  +  101  -> 232 ( and only shows 232)

or in HEx :  0060  + 0065  -> 00e8 ( and only shows 00e8 )

My problem now is that **I want to be able to  have access to both input key strokes ( eg 96 / 101 )** not the combined. (232) . How do I do that?

In addition I need to be able to distinguish other dead keys like backspace, linefeed, etc.

Comment: Are you writing a Visual Studio extension? Or why should it work within Visual Studio? Can you provide information re the programming language and technologies you are using?

Answer (score -1):

You could add a U+FEFF (ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE) between the two characters U+0060 and U+0065 this will keep the two characters separate but will also treat the three of them as a unit for line break opperations.